# Ruby regex to filter out word ending with a "string" suffix

Tags: ruby, regex, gitlab

I am trying to come up with a Ruby Regex that will match the following string:

```
MAINT: Refactor something
STRY-1: Add something
STRY-2: Update something
```

But should not match the following:

```
MAINT: Refactored something
STRY-1: Added something
STRY-2: Updated something

MAINT: Refactoring something
STRY-3: Adding something
STRY-4: Updating something
```

Basically, the first word after `:` should not end with either `ed` or `ing`

This is what I have currently:

```
^(MAINT|(STRY|PRB)-\d+):\s([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([a-zA-Z0-9._\-].*)
```

I have tried `[^ed]` and `[^ing]` but they would not work here since I am targeting more than single character.

I am not able to come up with a proper solution to achieve this.

Comment: @SagarPandya Using the `{0}` quantifier is identical to not putting the preceding character or group in the regex in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
^[-\w]+:\s*(?:(?!(?:ed|ing)\b)\w)+\b.+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6FmTpx/1/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
^                     # start of the line/string
[-\w]+:\s*            # match - and word characters, 1+ then :
(?:                   # non-capturing group
    (?!(?:ed|ing)\b)  # neg. lookahead: no ed or ing followed by a word boundary
    \w                # match a word character
)+\b                  # as long as possible, followed by a boundary
.*                    # match the rest of the string, if any
```

---

I have no experience in `Ruby` but I guess you could alternatively do a split and check if the second word ends with `ed` or `ing`. The latter approach might be easier to handle for future programmers/colleagues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This would have worked. But GitLab only supports Ruby version of Regex. Test of the same regex on http://rubular.com/ was not successful.

Comment: Note that your regex ends `.+` but in your explanation it ends `.*`. The latter doesn't do anything; it's not clear that the former is needed or wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
r = /
    \A             # match beginning of string
    (?:            # begin a non-capture group
      MAINT        # match 'MAINT'
      |            # or
      STRY\-\d+    # match 'STRY-' followed by one or more digits
    )              # end non-capture group
    :[ ]           # match a colon followed by a space
    [[:alpha:]]+   # match one or more letters
    (?<!           # begin a negative lookbehind
      ed           # match 'ed'
      |            # or
      ing          # match 'ing'
    )              # end negative lookbehind
    [ ]            # match a space
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode

   "MAINT: Refactor something".match?(r)   #=> true
   "STRY-1: Add something".match?(r)       #=> true
   "STRY-2: Update something".match?(r)    #=> true

   "MAINT: Refactored something".match?(r) #=> false
   "STRY-1: Added something".match?(r)     #=> false
   "STRY-2: Updated something".match?(r)   #=> false

   "A MAINT: Refactor something".match?(r) #=> false
   "STRY-1A: Add something".match?(r)      #=> false
```

This regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
r = /\A(?:MAINT|STRY\-\d+): [[:alpha:]]+(?<!ed|ing) /
```

Expressed this way the two spaces can each be represented a space character. In free-spacing mode, however, all spaces outside character classes are removed, which is why I needed to enclose each space in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

This is what I ended up using:

```
^(MAINT|(STRY|PRB)-\d+):\s(?:(?!(?:ed|ing)\b)[A-Za-z])+\s([a-zA-Z0-9._\-].*)
```